# How do I initialize UIView with strings in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, uiview, initialization

I have a UIView that plays videos. I have successfully played the video inside the view, however, I would like to pass in two string values in the view.

```
class CardView: UIView {
private var bucketname: String!
private var objectname: String!
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initialize()
}

convenience init(bucket: String, object: String){
    self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.bucketname = bucket
    self.objectname = object
    initialize()

}
private func initialize() {
    print(self.bucketname)
    print(self.objectname)
}
  }
```

I guess it is returning nil because the  self.init is called before I pass in the values, but I cant assign the values without calling self.init which calls initialize() without the values that I want to pass in. How do I get around this ?

Comment: You can take out the private on them and just assign the string values after initialization

Comment: How do I pass them in?

Comment: I want to pass them into the initialize dunxtion

Comment: What is nil in this? Your strings? or your UIView itself? The initialization looks fine. Convenience initializer is the way to go for what you want. I don't see a problem with your code.